# SII Suministro Inmediato Información - Cambiar endpoint en tiempo de ejecución

Tags: c#, webservice, soap, aeat-sii

Estoy realizando un proyecto en C# para el envío de facturas a través de del SII.

El proyecto está practicamente terminado, pero me gustaría saber si es posible (y como hacerlo) cambiar la url del endpoint en tiempo de ejecución, para que cuando active un checkbox, envíe a la url de pruebas o a la de producción.

He importado las WSDL en Visual Studio y explicado de forma rápida así es como tengo estructurado mi código:

```
using SII.WSDL_SuministroFacturasRecibidas; // El nombre que he asignado a la referencia de servicio

namespace SII
{
    public class SuministroFacturasRecibidas
    {
        public SuministroFacturasRecibidas()
        {
            // Creo el servicio
            siiService servicio = new siiService(); 

            // Proceso las facturas
            SuministroLRFacturasRecibidas suministroLRFacturasRecibidas = new SuministroLRFacturasRecibidas();
            suministroLRFacturasRecibidas.Cabecera = AnadirCabecera();
            suministroLRFacturasrecibidas.RegistroLRFacturasRecibidas = AnadirFacturas();

            // Añado el certificado digital al servicio
            servicio.ClientCertificates.Add(BuscarCertificado());

            // Trato la respuesta
            RespuestaLRFRecibidasType respuesta = servicio.SuministroLRFacturasRecibidas = suministroLRFacturasRecibidas;
            TratarRespuesta(respuesta);
        }
    }
}
```

El problema es que desde el momento que hago "siiService servicio = new siiService()" el servicio ya está recogiendo la url que se encuentra en la configuración en la ventana de propiedades del proyecto.

No se si hay alguna forma de poder cambiar dicha url o si estoy enfocando el proyecto de forma distinta a como debería hacerse. Es la primera vez que utilizo un webservice en un proyecto y por lo menos veo que las facturas se estan subiendo a hacienda.

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es posible cambiar la url en tiempo de ejecución y no veo ningún problema derivado de ello si lo haces antes de ejecutar ninguna consulta.

Cuando referencias un servicio en C# genera una clase proxy (en tu caso `siiService`) que encapsula todas las llamadas y propiedades que ha parseado del `wdsl` del servicio.
Entre esas propiedades, se encuentra una propiedad pública `Url` a la que se le da valor en el constructor.
Una vez instanciado, puedes cambiar el valor de esa propiedad sin problemas:

Usando el código que nos planteas como ejemplo:

```
using SII.WSDL_SuministroFacturasRecibidas; // El nombre que he asignado a la referencia de servicio

    namespace SII
    {
        public class SuministroFacturasRecibidas
        {
            public SuministroFacturasRecibidas()
            {
                // Creo el servicio
                siiService servicio = new siiService(); 
                servicio.Url = "http://urldelsercvicioactualizada.com";

                // Proceso las facturas
                SuministroLRFacturasRecibidas suministroLRFacturasRecibidas = new SuministroLRFacturasRecibidas();
                suministroLRFacturasRecibidas.Cabecera = AnadirCabecera();
                suministroLRFacturasrecibidas.RegistroLRFacturasRecibidas = AnadirFacturas();

                // Añado el certificado digital al servicio
                servicio.ClientCertificates.Add(BuscarCertificado());

                // Trato la respuesta
                RespuestaLRFRecibidasType respuesta = servicio.SuministroLRFacturasRecibidas = suministroLRFacturasRecibidas;
                TratarRespuesta(respuesta);
            }
        }
    }
```

En principio, por lo que nos comentas, la url que tiene asociada la referencia al servicio es la correcta por lo que no deberías cambiarla. No obstante, tienes la posibilidad de hacerlo si fuera necesario.

Esta no sería la única forma de hacerlo ni necesariamente la más elegante.
Una opción que (en caso de necesitarlo) podrías utilizar, sería la de modificar esa clase proxy con el sufijo "Service" que te ha generado el Visual Studio a través del wsdl para que en el constructor del mismo, le establezcas tu ya de base y no tengas que establecerla cada vez que la instancies.

Por norma general esta clase no está expuesta para su modificación al agregar una referencia al servicio, por lo que para modificar esa clase con nuestra necesidades tendríamos dos opciones:

### 1. Heredar

En lugar de modificar la clase proxy, generaremos la nuestra propia heredando de ella, y en nuestro constructor, haremos los ajustes que consideremos necesarios:

```
public class siiServicioWeb : siiService
{
    public siiServicioWeb ()
    {
        this.Url = "http://urldelsercvicioactualizada.com";
        //NOTA: Aquí podríamos añadir un método para cargar la url de alguna configuración, no hace falta que se encuentre hardcodeada.
    }

    public siiServicioWeb (string url)
    {
        this.Url = url;
    }
}
```

### 2. Generar la clase proxy por nosotros mismos

Si generamos nosotros la clase, podemos hacer las modificaciones que necesitemos sin problemas. Para evitar la tediosa tarea de interpretar el `wsdl` por nosotros mismos, hay un proceso de .NET llamado `wsdl.exe` que lo hará por nosotros. Podemos generar la clase a través del siguiente comando:

```
wsdl /language:cs  /protocol:SOAP /namespace:SII.ServicioWeb  /out:siiServicioWeb.cs /username:usuario /password:contraseña /domain:dominio http://host.com/path/al/wsdl
```

Los parámetros de `/username`, `/password` y `/domain` son obligatorios en caso de que el `wsdl` se encuentre protegido por credenciales.

Añado un enlace a la documentación del `wsdl.exe` por si fuera de interés. [Herramienta Lenguaje de descripción de servicios web](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/7h3ystb6(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: ¿Me creerías si te digo que busqué en todas las propiedades posibles y no se me ocurrió buscar por ese nombre? Como al llamar al constructor comprueba la url y si no es válida lanza una excepción, pensé que tenía que cambiar la url antes del constructor y no después. Muchas gracias

Comment: @aenon83 Vaya, no había visto que habías aceptado la respuesta mientras editaba. Nada, sin problemas, a veces uno simplemente necesita otro par de ojos ;) No obstante, te he proporcionado un par de alternativas para el caso en que te fuera necesario modificar la `url`, otras propiedades o el comportamiento de algún método. Espero que sirva de ayuda

Comment: He leido la modificación a tu respuesta y me ha parecido interesante. En principio voy a usar sólamente la opción de cambiar la url tras llamar al constructor en caso de querer usar la url de pruebas. Pero tendré en cuenta las otras opciones para futuros proyectos donde pueda ser más necesario. Gracias de nuevo

Comment: @aenon83 estupendo! En principio, esa es la opción más sencilla y directa (aunque la opción de la herencia es bastante limpia e inmediata también) todo depende de tus necesidades. De nada nuevo, para eso estamos aquí, uno se alegra de resultar útil.